# BibTeX -- runaway string warnings?

Tags: bibtex, strings

I get these runaway string warnings which don't seem to stop my LaTeX from compiling but are annoying. How the heck am I supposed to locate a "possible" runaway string which starts at line 152703??

I am using OverLeaf and as far as I have been able to determined (over about the last 5 years of use) are no listing of line numbers for my bibs. That is, I would have to count all the way to 152703 which is clearly tedious if not as clearly impossible.

> `BibTeX: warning: possible runaway string started at line 152703`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Comment: well you could download the bib and open it in some editor.

Comment: Does your bib file really contain more than 152000 lines?

Comment: [I see line numbers in bibtex files on overleaf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgQ83.png)

Comment: Is there possibly a percent sign in some field in your bibtex file?  Bibtex doesn't treat `%` as a special character, but when an unprotected `%` is read into TeX, the whole rest of that input line is ignored, and a necessary "terminator" could be lost.  Check in the `.bbl` file.